# IPTV: I'm can't get Stream URL

Tags: url, m3u

I'm creating a list with channel IPTV (Brazilian channels) for i use in my house.

I'm tryng to get a stream of an channel from url Using `URLHelper`, but not success.

[URL With Stream](http://tv-msn.com/TNT.php)

Before using `URLHelper` to get stream:

`rtmp://31.204.151.253/live?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MS8xMi8yMDE3IDY6MDc6MTUgUE0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1Kd1YrL3g5elRML0FtSUVsek1TRk1RPT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTIw<playpath>master77_1 <swfUrl>http://www.tv-msn.com/player/player.swf <pageUrl>http://tv-msn.com/TNT.php`

Now, before editions to write in M3u List

`rtmp://31.204.151.253/live/ playpath=master77_1 swfUrl=http://www.tv-msn.com/player/player.swf pageUrl=http://tv-msn.com/TNT.php` - Not worket

And before, i writed a token (is in `sfwUrl`)

`rtmp://31.204.151.253/live/ playpath=master77_1 swfUrl=http://www.tv-msn.com/player/player.swf pageUrl=http://tv-msn.com/TNT.php token=estoudevolta`

And the stream URL aren't working, but in URL with stream working.

How to put to work??